# Using Log4Fx with Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash-builder

Is it possible to [use](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/files/) [Log4Fx](http://cleartoolkit.com/?page_id=31)  with Flash Builder 4 ? The error I get is

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Clear Data Builder 4.1 4.1.0.201012071513 (com.farata.cleardatabuilder.feature.feature.group 4.1.0.201012071513)
  Missing requirement: DTO-to-Flex Annotations Processor 4.1.0.201012071513 (com.farata.dto2fx.asap 4.1.0.201012071513) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Clear Data Builder 4.1 4.1.0.201012071513 (com.farata.cleardatabuilder.feature.feature.group 4.1.0.201012071513)
    To: com.farata.dto2fx.asap [4.1.0.201012071513]
```